# Possible to re-use the same regex to anchor to different positions within a string?

Tags: javascript, regex, v8

What I want to do is find if a pattern matches at some fixed location within a string. This can be easily done by creating a custom regex just for the task:

```
console.log(/[^]{5}abc/.test('xxxxxabc'));
```

However, this allocates a new regex, which might be slow in a loop. Is there a way to re-use the same regex over and over for this? I was hoping this would work:

```
const r = /^abc/g;
r.lastIndex = 5;
console.log(r.test('xxxxxabc'));
```

...but no luck. `^` always anchors to the start of the string, never to the `lastIndex` as far as I can tell. Nor does this work:

```
const r = /abc/g;
r.lastIndex = 5;
console.log(r.test('xxxxxabc'));
```

...since it matches at or beyond the `lastIndex`. For reference, my use case is testing at various locations within a million+ character string, so performance is definitely of concern.

Comment: tl;dr: `/abc/y`

Comment: So simple! Bummed that I missed it in the docs. If you post it as an answer I'll accept it, thanks.

Comment: `/y` is fairly new, just a heads-up.